# IMarketBillingService do not created. Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to implement In-app Billing app

Have some problems with IMarketBillingService.java-file creating.

I do these steps:

Create the following directory in your application's /src directory:
com/android/vending/billing/

Copy the IMarketBillingService.aidl file into the sample/src/com/android/vending/billing/ directory.

Build your application.

But in /gen  I can not find a generated interface file.
I use Android 3.0..

When I add IMarketBillingService.aidl to project with API 8 -- all is ok..
IMarketBillingService.java is creating..

any suggestions?

Comment: So your building against Android version 11 and it doesn't work, but building against version 8 it does?

Comment: Right! For sdk 11 file IMarketBillingService.java doesn't create for me.
I added IMarketBillingService.aidl to com/android/vending/billing/ directory project automatically rebuild but in /gen directory is only R.java..
I tried also manual rebuild..
IMarketBillingService.java doesn't create..

Comment: But for SDK 8 it does create? That doesn't make sense. You must be changing something else